# How can I perform CRUD operations to a specific azure database in my Sql server object explorer and not a default connection database?

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-5, connection-string, crud

**Connection String**

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Connect" 
connectionString="Server=tcp:players.database.windows.net,1433;Initial 
Catalog=eManagerDB;Persist Security Info=False;User
  ID=evanligon;Password=*******;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" />
```

I know this connection string works because I am currently using it for the initial project that created the database in the first place. 
I've already connected the database to my object explorer, I just can't seem to update it. I only seem to be updating a "default connection" database
When I launch it.

**Web.Config**

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
 </configuration>
```

*PS This project runs perfect locally using the default database, so the code seems to be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to publish your application and your database to Azure as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/publish-to-azure).

[image]

[image]